# Unique pageviews in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Under **Content** → **Pages** in Google Analytics, it says that unique page views are counted for each unique combination of page URL and page title. Is the hash field a part of the URL in this context? Are `/myUrl` and `/myUrl#section1` counted as two different page views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it shouldn't count it as 2 different URLs. While I'm not 100% on this, you can always check yourself by searching for it in Analytics.

Just go to the **Content** → **Site Content** → **All Pages** and use the search bar in the middle of the page to search for `/myUrl#section1` — if nothing comes up then you know the stats are being rolled into `/myUrl`.

Comment: Thanks, and good tip :) I can't find any URLs with hash values in the list, so I guess they're not counted as multiple page views.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is that your browser does not reload the page, when you use hash as a means of local link `/` on-page anchor.

The Google Analytics code is per default only executed when the page is loaded—and browsers doesn't reload the page when you click on a hash.